# How do I fetch data out of mongodb out of an async function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, promise

I am relatively new to JavaScript and especially new to promise. I am struggling to get the second console.log() to output the same as the first one. Is this even possible? Do I have to do all of my code using that uses the kittens data inside of the async function?

```js
  async function getKittens() {
    const kittens = await Kitten.find();
    console.log(kittens);
    return(kittens)
  }
  console.log(getKittens());
```

When this is ran I get (the promise is from the console.log() outside of the async function.

```js
Promise { <pending> }
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("633499451739979630b645be"),
    name: 'Silence',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6334998b51a957972355eb63"),
    name: 'Silence',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Comment: What happens if you set a variable to the output of the `getMembers()` function and then try to `console.log()` that?

Comment: Same output. Another `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: I think you need `await` there, similar to how you're assigning the `kittens` variable

Comment: I tried using 
```
getKittens().then((value) => {
 return value
}
```
But this didn't work either. Am I using .then() wrong?

Answer (score 0):

All, `async` functions return a promise so the caller of your function needs to use `await` or `.then()` to get the final result.   This is because the `async` function returns a promise as soon as your function hits its first `await`.  The result is not known yet when the function returns.

There is no magic way to turn an asynchronously retrieved value into a synchronously retrieved value, even with `await`.  And no way to directly return from your function the asynchronously retrieved value.  The function will return before the value is known.

If you're retrieving the value asynchronously, then anyone using that value outside of your function will have to use `await` or `.then()` to get access to the value.

```
async function getKittens() {
  const kittens = await Kitten.find();
  console.log(kittens);
  return(kittens)
}

getKittens().then(kittens => {
    console.log(kittens);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

To understand the timing of things a little better, if you insert these diagnostic messages:

```
async function getKittens() {
  console.log("in getKittens()");
  const kittens = await Kitten.find();
  console.log("after await Kitten.find()");
  return(kittens)
}

console.log("about to call getKittens()");    
let p = getKittens();
console.log("after calling getKittens()");
p.then(kittens => {
    console.log("got result from getKittens()");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

You will see this in the console:

```
about to call getKittens()
in getKittens()
after calling getKittens()
after await Kitten.find()
got result from getKittens()
```

Note that the function has returned BEFORE the `await` has finished and before the result of `Kitten.find()` is known.

Answer (score 0):

Try once like this:

```
async function getKittens() {
    const kittens = await Kitten.find();
    console.log(kittens);
    return kittens;
  }
  getKittens().then(kittens=>{
    console.log(kittens);
  }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```